# Get top 10 unique vendor data based on sub query which return vendor id

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `FileMaster` and `VendorMaster`.
In `VendorMaster` i have vendor id and other stuff. in `FileMaster` i have file related data where 'Vendorid' is `foreign key` in `FileMaster`. Now I want to fetch top 10 data from `FileMaster` for Each 'Vendor' (One record for one vendor).

I have tried below query, but it returns me 10 records with duplicate vendorID

```
select top 10 * from FileMaster where VendorId in (select  top 10 VendorId from VendorMaster)
```

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT` keyword in your query

Comment: Add some sample data for better understanding.

Comment: If possible put some expected output data so we can better understand what you getting and what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER. I assumed FileID column for the identity of File Master. By the way, you don't need any subquery

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (
    select  *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VendorID ORDER BY FileID) AS RN 
    FROM FileMaster ) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY FileID
```

Comment: It worked. can you explain me little bit `RN = 1` what it is used for ?

Comment: First, FileMaster table sorted for each vendor by using ROW_NUMBER. And gets first items of each vendor with RN = 1. It makes the result unique for each vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use simple way instead of `subquery`

Or Anther way you can use `CTE` click this [Link](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-sql-server/)

```
SELECT DISTINCT FM.* 
FROM FileMaster FM WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[VendorMaster] VM WITH(NOLOCK)
ON FM.VendorId  = VM.VendorId 
ORDER BY FM.VendorId ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

For more details `OFFSET` related check this [Link](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/)